# In a class with two timers, do they execute in two separate threads?

Tags: java, timer

In a java class I have two timers

```
TimerTask t1 = new TimerTask() {.. }
TimerTask t2 = new TimerTask() { ...}
```

Do `t1` and `t2` execute as two separate threads? How do you verify it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to put each `TimeTask` in a `Timer`, which will spawn off the thread.  From the API manual for `Timer`:

> Corresponding to each Timer object is
>   a single background thread that is
>   used to execute all of the timer's
>   tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks
>   should complete quickly. If a timer
>   task takes excessive time to complete,
>   it "hogs" the timer's task execution
>   thread. This can, in turn, delay the
>   execution of subsequent tasks, which
>   may "bunch up" and execute in rapid
>   succession when (and if) the offending
>   task finally completes.